# PHP: Reading a file which contains an undefined function?

Tags: php, file, undefined-function

Stumbled across a bit of an annoying problem.

I have a need to pull a specific line of text out of a php file programmatically. (Its a plugin version number within a comment)

Seems straightforward enough, however the file I am attempting to read contains within it a function which is undefined as far as the script attempting to open it is concerned.

Is there anyway I can read the file using PHP's built in functions, so far file_get_contents(), file() and readfile() all suffer from the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

------------------------------------------- UPDATE

Ok well it seems my previous errors must have been down to a caching issue as it appears to be working without any Undefined Function errors, although now my return array just appears to be empty?

**Reader Script**

```
<?php

//some other code

//lines in question
$lines = file('path/to/file.php');          
$data['Version']=$lines[6];

?>
```

**File Being Read**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Wordfence Security
Plugin URI: http://www.wordfence.com/
Description: Wordfence Security - Anti-virus, Firewal and Site Speedup
Author: Wordfence
Version: 5.0.6
Author URI: http://www.wordfence.com/
*/
if(defined('WP_INSTALLING') && WP_INSTALLING){
    return;
}
define('WORDFENCE_VERSION', '5.0.6');
if(get_option('wordfenceActivated') != 1){
    add_action('activated_plugin','wordfence_save_activation_error'); function wordfence_save_activation_error(){ update_option('wf_plugin_act_error',  ob_get_contents()); }
}
if(! defined('WORDFENCE_VERSIONONLY_MODE')){
    if((int) @ini_get('memory_limit') < 64){
        if(strpos(ini_get('disable_functions'), 'ini_set') === false){
            @ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); //Some hosts have ini set at as little as 32 megs. 64 is the min sane amount of memory.
        }
    }
    require_once('lib/wordfenceConstants.php');
    require_once('lib/wordfenceClass.php');
    wordfence::install_actions();
}

?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` and the other methods you listed doesn't care about what's inside the file. To those functions, the PHP code would look like plaintext, nothing else. Are you using `eval()` somewhere?

Comment: Contains an undefined function? Do you mean it _calls_ an undefined function? Also, what is that same issue you encounter with the file functions?

Comment: It would be useful to include a representative sample PHP file and also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Maybe the [runkit](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)-extension is useful to you. In particular the `runkit_import`-function. Have a look at [runkit_sandbox_output_handler](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-sandbox-output-handler.php) for some example code aswell.

Comment: "file_get_contents() and the other methods you listed doesn't care about what's inside the file. To those functions, the PHP code would look like plaintext, nothing else. Are you using eval() somewhere?" This was what I had expected but it keeps returning null, and when I check the PHP error logs I am getting a Undefined Function Error coming from the script I am attempting to read.